# Handle exceptions thrown asynchronously in Java

Tags: java, exception, transactions, try-catch

Below is an example of a `try/finally` block I'm having difficulty with. In the `try` block, I have two methods that may throw different exceptions. The code in these methods involves Hibernate-managed transactions.

My issue is, it's not until `cleanup()` is invoked that both of the exceptions are thrown from the methods in the `try` block.

I need to invoke `cleanup()` whether the exceptions are thrown or not. How can I get around this?

```
try
{
    mayThrowException1();
    mayThrowException2();
}
finally
{
    cleanup();
}
```

Comment: `cleanup()` is already invoked whether the exceptions are thrown or not, that's the purpose of the `finally` keyword.

Comment: @Ricola Sorry yes I know that, but when the exceptions are thrown while `cleanup()` is being invoked, they interrupt that method so it doesn't finish executing properly.

Comment: You should give a more complete example, but maybe you could use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)